# Where does 'system:time_start' come from?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

From EE resources [1,2] I see references to `system:time_start` like:

```
// This field contains UNIX time in milliseconds.
var timeField = 'system:time_start';
```

I guess that's used to register the start point of a time series (right?). But my question is how would I find it, where is the `system:time_start` documented?

I tried to search the `Docs` tab on EE online code editor (left side) but nothing returned.

[1]https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_info
[2]https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mNIRB90jwLuASO1JYas1kuOXCLbOoy1Z4NlV1qIXM10/edit

Comment: Check out the `system:time_start` entry in the GEE glossary: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/glossary - looks like it's Unix-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system:time_start` is documented in the Google Earth Engine API
[Glossary](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/glossary)